# How to name constraints in C++

Tags: c++, cplex

I've written code in c++ and I'm calling CPLEX from there to solve a MILP problem. I'm getting a few errors and to narrow down the point from where the errors are originating from, I want to give different names to the constraints. However, I'm not able to get any sort of info on how to do this. I'm using `IloExpr` to create expression for the constraints and then I'm adding them to the model. A snippet of one of the constraints is shown below. Here, `x[i][d]` is a boolean decision variable. Please help me with naming such constraints.

```
for (i=0;i<I;i++)
    {
        IloExpr not_more_than_one (env);
        for (d=0;d<D;d++)
        {
            not_more_than_one += x[i][d];
        }
        mod.add(not_more_than_one <= 1);
        not_more_than_one.end();
    }
```

Comment: For those that put this question on hold (and/or downvoted), please explain what is not clear about the question. I think this question is quite clear as is, for someone that is familiar with CPLEX.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In order to set the constraint name you should use an [IloRange](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refcppcplex/html/classes/IloRange.html). For example, you could replace the following line from your snippet:

```
mod.add(not_more_than_one <= 1);
```

with:

```
IloRange cons(env, not_more_than_one, 1, "name of the constraint");
model.add(cons);
```

Comment: To those that downvoted this answer, please see the edit history and consider changing your vote. Also, note that the answer was already accepted.